# How to make young software engineers improve the quality of their output?

Tags: project-management

During our last project, our team composed of young software engineers made a product which contains much more bugs than other teams. We have a senior engineer who was part of the team, but isn't much involved in the development process as he has been promoted to manager. He just reviewed the team's code for the first time and found a lot of issues.

This team has shown strong capabilities in the past, but the result of our last project got me worried. 
What the team members said about this last project:

- It is more complicated than our previous ones: lots of requirement change, complex interactions with the database, complex UI, new technologies...
- Not enough time, too much pressure
- Hard to understand the requirement (however we made sure everybody understands the requirements thoroughly during the project)

I trust my team, they are really good people. What can I do to make them improve their output?

Comment: How are you managing bugs?  How are you managing the development cycle?  What priority is there on quality?  If you can't measure it you can't manage it.

Comment: Most of the bugs popped out at the end of the project. The senior engineer said it was due to bad code.

Comment: Are you doing code reviews?  Pair programming?  Perhaps utilising a methodology like Agile may also help, if you are not already.  Instead of a monolithic testing effort at the end, you can test after each iteration and push bugs back into the backlog to be addressed.

Comment: We are using Agile. The team has been doing code reviews regularly (without the senior engineer). Their opinion about the code contradict the opinion of the senior engineer. For them, the code is ok. QA tested at each iteration, and as I said, it is only at the end that a lot of bugs appeared.

Comment: You need to fire your QA or your testers then.  Why didn't they pick the bugs up during each iteration?  Or did your team rush the last iteration and introduce the bugs then?

Comment: I would rather believe that the last iteration was rushed. QA have done a great job in the past finding highly non trivial bugs. They got praised from other teams.

Comment: Can you track when these bugs were introduced?  That should give you an indication of the cause so you can try to plan around it.  Don't be afraid to manage upwards (as early as possible) if the timeframes are too tight and introduces the risk of additional bugs!

Comment: What you would rather believe isn't the question. Testing may have been inadequate -- it often is. You nee to go back and look at what the bugs were, when they were introduced, and why they weren't caught.  And if you're really using Agile properly there should always be a last-known-good you can release when the release date hits, even if it doesn't have all the features -- or you take the hit and slip the date;.

Comment: Do you have a Business Analyst on the team in charge of the requirements and use cases? Do you also have a project manager on the team assigning the tasks and controlling the timeline (as well as reporting to management on how well the team is sticking to the deadline)?

Comment: Note that the subject line really should be how to _help_  them 's improve quality, especially if you're arguing it wasn't entirely their fault...

Comment: I would suggest "make them improve" is the wrong tone.  If you made sure everybody understands the requirements thoroughly during the project then why is the team saying the requirements are hard to understand.  The senior engineer only reviewed the code recently. This team has shown strong capabilities in the past.  It reads a bit like you want to blame the team rather fix the process.   I see you are in Beijing so it may just be a language thing.  Make is force.

Comment: Tongue in cheek answer: Q: "How do you make young engineers improve the quality of their output?" A: "The same way you make old engineers improve the quality of their output." Others here are hinting that you are putting the blame in the wrong place, but I'll come right out and say it: age is not the concern. It is possible that *experience* might be a factor; experience often has a correlation to age, but don't blame the juniors just because they are juniors. That used to annoy the heck out of me when I was younger, and I generally proved that my work was not the problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To coalesce the comments into an answer, it seems as though the issue isn't specifically your team, but rather a *management issue* and having difficulty managing towards a tight deadline that led to rushing the final sprint.  From the comments above:

> We are using Agile. The team has been doing code reviews regularly (without the senior engineer). Their opinion about the code contradict the opinion of the senior engineer. For them, the code is ok. QA tested at each iteration, and as I said, it is only at the end that a lot of bugs appeared.

It sounds like you are doing the right things *within* the team.  However:

> I would rather believe that the last iteration was rushed. QA have done a great job in the past finding highly non trivial bugs. They got praised from other teams

It's easy to say that the problem revolves around that point, but looking deeper the issue is one of not necessarily managing the scope of each *previous* iteration to ensure the timeframe was realistic and not put undue pressure on the last sprint.

So how do you avoid this?  Well, what you need to do is to track your progress against your delivery date.  How many modules are left, and will it fit based on your current burndown rate and planned iterations?  Do you have to make allowances for any bugs you've come across?  If there is a discrepancy, **raise it as early as possible** so that you can either reduce scope or push out your deadline.

Your team seem to be doing the right things with regard to code quality.  Where the issue seems to lie is in managing your sprint planning and tracking against your scope and delivery date.

Comment: Good answer. I would add that since the senior engineer (now manager) has found issues that the young team did not recognize, it would be prudent to involve the/a senior engineer in each of the iterations to review the code  and mentor the younger ones. Hopefully the company organization would facilitate that type of involvement. Better code reviews will slow down the team velocity (for a time) but would pay off in the long run.

Answer (score 5):

I would involve a senior person much earlier in code review in this case. We require code review before code can be pushed to QA. And then I would consider taking the code review advice and developng training from it if ther are consistent problems.  But the single most critical piece in improving the qualit yof juniors is to not fix their code, but to make them fix it. They will learn more from doing the actual fixes once problems are identified. Make sure to explain why the items identified are problems instead of just flagging them.